# Optimal number of clusters - Error in FUNcluster(x, i, ...) : more cluster centers than distinct data points

Tags: numbers, cluster-computing, optimal

I have these data and I need to find the optimal number of clusters of this table.
The values can be either 0, 0.5 or 1

```
library(NbClust)
library(factoextra)
library(pheatmap)

    tab=structure(list(`57-B1` = c(1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.5), `57-B3` = c(0.5,
0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5), `57-C1` = c(1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5),
    `57-C5` = c(1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1), `57-H2` = c(1, 0.5, 0.5,
    0, 1, 1), `57-H4` = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5), `61-1-B1` = c(0.5,
    0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5), `61-1-C2` = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5,
    0.5), `61-1-C5` = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5), `61-1-H1` = c(0.5,
    0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5), `61-1-H3` = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5,
    0.5), `61-1-H5` = c(0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), `62-2_H2` = c(0.5,
    0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5), `62_1_C2` = c(0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5,
    0.5), `62_1_C5` = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5), `FL-39-C3` = c(0.5,
    0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5), `FL-41-1-C3` = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0,
    0.5, 0.5), `FL-57-B1` = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5), `FL-57-B2` = c(0.5,
    0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5), `FL-57-C2` = c(0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5,
    0.5, 0.5), `FL-57-C3` = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1), `FL-57-C5` = c(1,
    0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1), `FL-57-H1` = c(1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1),
    `FL-57-H4` = c(0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5), `FL-57-H5` = c(0.5,
    0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5), `FL-61-1-B1` = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0,
    0.5, 0.5), `FL-61-1-B4` = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5),
    `FL-61-1-C2` = c(0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5), `FL-61-1-C4` = c(0.5,
    0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5), `FL-61-1-H3` = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0,
    0.5, 0.5), `FL-61-1-H4` = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5),
    `FL-61-1-H5` = c(0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), `FL-62-1-C3` = c(0.5,
    0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), `FL-62-2-H2` = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0,
    0.5, 0.5), `FL-73-H1` = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5), P_57_F = c(0.5,
    0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5), P_57_M = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5,
    0.5)), row.names = c("g1", "g2", "g3", "g4", "g5", "g6"), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried both on scaled and non-scale values:

```
fviz_nbclust(scale(tab), kmeans, method = "wss") 
fviz_nbclust(tab, kmeans, method = "wss")
```

and I get this error:

```
Error in FUNcluster(x, i, ...) :
  more cluster centers than distinct data points.
```

how can I fix it?

Many thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I maybe found the solutions: it was sufficient to specify k.max = any number lower than nrow(tab)